# How to correctly count words using strtok?

Tags: c, string, strtok

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

  char tekst[10000], test=0;
  char* word;
  char word_copy[100][100];
  int i=0, lenght=0;

  printf("Type in your text: ");
  fgets(tekst, 10000, stdin);

  lenght=strlen(tekst)-1;
  if(lenght>1000)
  {
    lenght=1000;
  }

  word=strtok(tekst, " ,\".-");

  while( word != NULL)
    {
      word=strtok(NULL, " ,\".-");
      printf("%s ", word);
      i++;

    }

  printf("%d", i);
```

Hello. What I want to do, is to count words only by using strtok. However, if i type: "example" or -example-, i get the answer "2" instead of "1". For some reason, when the last word is (null), it still triggers the loop, and i++ works... I'm pretty new to programming, so i would aprreciate writing the correct code down aswell.

Comment: don't try to print `NULL` for starters. Test if NULL before printing it.

Comment: and break when strtok return NULL so you don't count it.

Comment: It's not too early to learn how to use a debugger to figure out what's happening in your program.

Comment: You count `word` even when it's null.  Use `while ((word = strtok(NULL, " ,\".-")) != NULL) { printf("%s ", word); i++; }`.

Comment: Actually, I know i should use strcpy or test it before printing, but I was confused and needed some quick information back and left it here while copying, haha. And thank you very much. I've tried breaking the while earlier, but I was using "word" in the if, and this time I've tried full "strtok(..)", as suggested, and it worked! I really appreciate your help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from the comments, here's one more way to fix your code:

```
...
char *text = tekst;
while((word = strtok(text, " ,\".-"))) {
    text = NULL;
    printf("%s ", word);
    i++;
}
...
```

Comment: GCC will warn about the assignment in a conditional with very little provocation (`-Wall` etc).  I'd write `while ((word = strtok(text, " ,\".-")) != NULL)` to avoid that warning — at no cost in the generated code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was surprised that gcc 5.4.0 did not issue that warning (with -Wall and -pedantic).

Comment: The extra parentheses are a symbol to GCC that you know what you're doing. (Otoh, MSVC complains regardless.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the trailing newline of `fgets()`, like mentioned in [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).

Then, I removed the not used stuff of your code, like length.

As the example in `strtok()`'s [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) mentions, you first take the token, and then you call the function again. With that approach, you don't need to worry about counting `NULL` as a word (which your code did).

Putting everything together, we get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

  char tekst[10000];
  char* word;
  int i=0;

  printf("Type in your text: ");
  fgets(tekst, 10000, stdin);
  tekst[strcspn(tekst, "\n")] = 0;

  word=strtok(tekst, " ,\".-");

  while( word != NULL)
  {
      printf("%s ", word);
      word=strtok(NULL, " ,\".-");
      i++;

  }

  printf("%d", i);

  return 0;
}
```

Output (Input: "stack-overflow"):

> Type in your text: stack overflow 2

---

PS: [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) returns the length of the string without the null terminator, no need to subtract by yourself.